# Unexpected error while trying to federate users between two Keycloaks (Wrong audience from token)

Tags: keycloak

I have two keycloaks, one is 6.x (parent IDP) and the other is 3.x (child IDP) and when trying to federate users from the parent to child Im encountering an unexpected error. The stack trace of the child IDP,

```
Failed to make identity provider oauth callback: org.keycloak.broker.provider.IdentityBrokerException: Could not fetch attributes from userinfo endpoint.
    at org.keycloak.broker.oidc.OIDCIdentityProvider.getFederatedIdentity(OIDCIdentityProvider.java:366)
Caused by: org.keycloak.broker.provider.IdentityBrokerException: Wrong audience from token.
```

But as per the documentation I have configured both the IDPs and if I try to federate from parent to child it work seamlessly, does any one know the root cause for this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because from version 4.6.0 its been decided not to add audience attribute to the token. This is the reason why the older keycloak is complaining about wrong audience in the token.

Inorder to resolve this , go to the parent IDP's client scope
Step 1
Create a client scope "aud_scope"
Step 2
In the setting of this scope Create a protocol mapper

- Name: audience-mapper
- Choose Mapper type: Audience
- Included Client Audience: the name of the federating client
- Add to access token: on

Then go to federating client and in the client scope settings tab,

Add available client scopes "aud_scope" to assigned default client scopes